# Unable to build precompile.exe

Tags: protobuf-net

- Release: r668
- Environments: Tried both VS12 on Win7 and Xamarin Studio on OS X 10.11.5
- Errors:

  - Program.cs:317: RuntimeTypeModel does not contain a definition for 'Universe'.
  - A handful of similar instances of 'Universe' being an unknown symbol.
  - Program.cs:397: RuntimeTypeModel does not contain a definition for 'Cascade'.
  - Program.cs:418: CompilerOptions does not contain a definition for 'KeyContainer'.
  - Program.cs:419: CompilerOptions does not contain a definition for 'KeyFile'.
  - Program.cs:420: CompilerOptions does not contain a definition for 'PublicKey'.
  - A bunch of follow-on errors.

I am guessing that I either have a bad configuration somehow or the wrong version of IKVM? Of the latter I tried both with the embedded version and with the one shipped on nuget.

With either configuration I tried, I am able to build the core protobuf-net assembly as well as protogen.exe just fine.

Any ideas I might try? Are anyone able to build precompile?